# Detecting mouse/stylus clicks with C# on a combobox in .NET CF

Tags: c#, mobile, mouse, mouseevent, .net-cf-3.5

I´m trying to detect when a combobox in my Windows Mobile application is hit by a mouse click. Unfortunately this component in .NET CF2.0 doesn´t have a MouseClick event (whereas Desktop .NET does). Does someone have an idea of how to catch mouse/stylus clicks over the items list of a combobox using C#?

Thank you!

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105504/the-net-cf-combobox-doesnt-have-a-dropdown-event-so-whats-the-alternative

Comment: Hi Davide. Thanks for your idea, but it will not help me to differ whereas the input comes from mouse or from hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the MouseDown/MouseUp events to get the same behavior as MouseClick.  You will just have to make sure the object is the same is both cases and store some state between events.

Comment: I´m very grateful for your idea, but these events doesn´t occur in Combobox component in Compact Framework either. Could I have another idea?